# django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2026, 'SSL connection error: Unable to get certificate')

Tags: django, jenkins, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to get run some tasks in a Django application on Jenkins. Django is failing to connect to the MySQL database on Jenkins(which is on a mac). I should note everything works fine locally. I am going to share some of my settings:

**Databases From Settings**

```
DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'HOST': '<myhost>',
            'NAME': '<myname>',
            'USER': '<myuser>',
            'OPTIONS': {
                'ssl': {
                    'ca': os.environ.get('SSL_CA_CERT_PATH'),
                    'cert': os.environ.get('SSL_CLIENT_CERT_PATH'),
                    'key': os.environ.get('SSL_CLIENT_KEY_PATH')
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The environment variables for the cert paths do actually seem to work which I find odd. I have debugged with the following python commands in my settings and it does print out the expected results (file paths and file contents):

```
print(os.environ.get('SSL_CA_CERT_PATH'))
txt_opn = open(str(os.environ.get('SSL_CA_CERT_PATH')))
print(txt_opn.read())
print(os.environ.get('SSL_CLIENT_CERT_PATH'))
txt_opn = open(str(os.environ.get('SSL_CLIENT_CERT_PATH')))
print(txt_opn.read())
print(os.environ.get('SSL_CLIENT_KEY_PATH'))
txt_opn = open(str(os.environ.get('SSL_CLIENT_KEY_PATH')))
print(txt_opn.read())
```

**Error Message**

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2026, 'SSL connection error: Unable to get certificate')
```

I have the certs in a Shared folder and chmod 777 everything. I do not have permission to chown to mysql:mysql however, even with sudo:

```
Sorry, user <myuser> is not allowed to execute '/usr/sbin/chown mysql:mysql client-cert.pem' as root on <myhost>.
```

Lastly, in case is it is relevant, here is what I am running as a jenkins shell script to kick of the tasks. Bare in mind there are many unseen jenkins parameters being used here. Settings is just my --settings, and everything else is pretty self explanatory.

**Jenkins Shell Script**

```
export SSL_CA_CERT_PATH=$SSL_CA_CERT_PATH
export SSL_CLIENT_CERT_PATH=$SSL_CLIENT_CERT_PATH
export SSL_CLIENT_KEY_PATH=$SSL_CLIENT_KEY_PATH

echo "Making Virtual Environment..."
/usr/local/bin/virtualenv venv
source ./venv/bin/activate

echo "Installing Requirements..."
pip install -r requirements.txt --process-dependency-links

echo "Making Migrations..."
python manage.py makemigrations $SETTINGS

echo "Migrating Database Schema..."
python manage.py migrate $SETTINGS

echo "Running Jobs..."
IFS=',' read -r -a jobs_array <<< "$JOBS"
for JOB in "${jobs_array[@]}"
do
  if [ "$GROUPED" = true ]; then
    echo "Preparing to start Job Group $JOB..."
    python manage.py runjobs $JOB $SETTINGS
  else
    echo "Preparing to start $JOB job..."
    python manage.py runjob $JOB $SETTINGS
  fi
done

echo "Jobs Completed!"
```

I have been searching for an answer far and wide and have yet been able to find something that works. Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will post my solution in case it helps someone out in the future, but the problem was one of my Jenkins parameters was not set correctly. If anyone else encounters this issue, please double check all your parameters, their spelling, and the paths they may be referring to.

Comment: Also make sure you have all correct rights to connect to the database (e.g. remote IP validation)